# GlassFish v2.1 -- getting Application Client and Eclipselink to work together?

Tags: glassfish

We are trying to use Eclipselink 1.1 with Glassfish v2.1. Following the instructions on:
http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FaqEclipseLinkGlassFishV2

I adapted the instructions for the appclient script on linux by adding the lines:

> APPCPATH=$APPCPATH:$AS_INSTALL/lib/eclipselink-1.1.1.jar
>   export APPCPATH
>   to the appclient shell script.

This however is not working. On running the application client (using Glassfish's webstart), I get the error:
WARNING: "IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList"

Anyone else succeed in getting GF v 2.1 to work with eclipselink? or any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

I found this bug report:
http s://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8204
(New users can't post more than 1 link, so remove the space between 'http' and 's'.)

Where Tim Quinn (tjquinn) said:

> App client container support for persistence is not yet in place

I think this refers only to Glassfish v3, and it should be working in Glassfish v2. Is this correct? I'm working on the assumption that this will work once the ACC knows where to find the eclipselinks jar.

Thanks in advance,
Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, according to tjquinn,

> Yes, the issue refers to v3 (and it
>   has been fixed in v3).
>
> Changes to the appclient script have
>   no effect on clients launched using
>   the built-in support for Java Web
>   Start.
>
> Could you please try this: Add the
>   EclipseLink jar to the domain's
>   lib/ext directory. Add to the client
>   JAR's manifest a dependency on the
>   EclipseLink extension. This will allow
>   the built-in Java Web Start support in
>   GlassFish to detect the dependency and
>   make then make sure the EclipseLink
>   jar is downloaded as needed to support
>   your client.
>
> And of course let us know how this
>   goes!
>
> Tim

We'll try this and post the results.