# Security exception when moving from toplink to eclipselink in glassfish 2.1

Tags: glassfish

My app is working fine with toplink, but I need some eclipselink features, so I decided to swap.

I changed the provider in `persistence.xml` to:

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

and added the following property (though I'm not sure if this is needed):

```
<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/>
```

I've tried packaging `eclipselink.jar` with my app, and I've tried putting it in `$GFHOME/lib` and adding it to the classpath suffix through the glassfish admin ui. Whatever I do, I get:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.1.3.v20091002-r5404): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MYAPP] failed.
Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.1.3.v20091002-r5404): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MYAPP] failed.
Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:878)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:149)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.load(PersistenceUnitLoaderImpl.java:84)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.AbstractLoader.loadPersistenceUnits(AbstractLoader.java:895)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.ApplicationLoader.doLoad(ApplicationLoader.java:184)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.TomcatApplicationLoader.doLoad(TomcatApplicationLoader.java:126)
        <snip>
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.1.3.v20091002-r5404): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MYAPP] failed.
Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:210)
        ... 82 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission createClassLoader)
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkCreateClassLoader(SecurityManager.java:594)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.<init>(SecureClassLoader.java:53)
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader$DelegatingClassLoader.<init>(EJBClassLoader.java:1368)
        at com.sun.enterprise.loader.EJBClassLoader.copy(EJBClassLoader.java:384)
        at com.sun.enterprise.server.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getNewTempClassLoader(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:216)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformBase.getNewTempClassLoader(ServerPlatformBase.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:741)
        ... 81 more
```

and the app does not deploy.

**Edit - I tried changing to security settings but ran into another problem**

I would have though the following (in server.policy already) would have allowed
`eclipselink.jar` full access, but apparently not.

```
// Core server classes get all permissions by default
grant codeBase "file:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I added the following:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

And now I get:

```
WARNING: "IOP00810257: (MARSHAL) Could not load class org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList"
```

on the client side

**Edit** which I've just realised is [GlassFish v2.1 -- getting Application Client and Eclipselink to work together?](https://serverfault.com/questions/55662) and having ensured the jar gets bundled with the app, it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base cause is that GlassFish runs with the SecurityManager enabled and EclipseLink does not have all the required permissions to run within GlassFish V2.  TopLink Essentials is given special permissions for GlassFish and to resolve your issue simply extend these permissions to EclipseLink.  This [blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/paulsen/entry/configuring_the_security_manager_in) goes into nice detail on how to configure the security policy for GlassFish.

--Gordon

Comment: Hmm. I've got the jar in $GFHOME/lib/eclipselink.jar and the following was already in server.policy which surely allows it full access? I've made sure the jar isn't also packaged with the application.

// Core server classes get all permissions by default
grant codeBase "file:${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};